# Using Max() function in MySql returns wrong value

Tags: mysql, max

I've a table with SN and titles
In the first query i do :

```
create or replace view AB as
select wrote.serial_number as SN, count(wrote.serial_number) as NumOfPapers
from wrote
group by wrote.serial_number;
```

and i DO get a view with SN and the count of the titles per SN
than i want to get the ROW with the most titles (max of count) as : ID | max(count)
so i do :

```
select AB.SN, max(AB.NumOfPapers)
from AB
```

but i get the max number of the counts with the first row person's SN (not the real SN with the most titles)

I have to use max() ... thanks for the suggestions using 'order by' but they are not relevant here

What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: You forgot to provide criteria for selecting the appropriate SN.

Comment: `select AB.SN, max(AB.NumOfPapers)
from AB` is not valid SQL. (though mysql will not complain about it). You forgot the `group by` clause.

Comment: It seems valid in all the websites i looked for the max() syntax.

Comment: It **is** invalid. Read this to understand why MySQL allows despite being invalid (and the consequences): http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Comment: @SagiLow The `MAX` function by itself does not require a `GROUP BY` clause, but one is required if you ask for other columns in the `SELECT` clause.  `SELECT MAX(NumOfPapers) FROM ab` is perfectly valid because you are asking for the result of an analytical function across the entire table.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT sn
FROM   ab
ORDER BY NumOfPapers DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: If i use the order by on the created view and limit it to 1 it will work as well, but it's like i'm not using the max() ... just ordering and taking the highest... shouldn't the max() return the complete row ?

Comment: look what i suggested you sagilow , u will use max

Comment: That didn't work ... it returned the first SN on the list together with the highest SN exists... (i think as expected?), i'm not sure if i was clear enough but i DO look for the max COUNT ...

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're only getting the first row's count of NumOfPapers is because you are also selecting the ab.serial number.  So, I think this will give you what you're looking for:

```
select AB.SN, AB.NumOfPapers FROM AB order by AB.NumOfPapers desc limit 1;
```

Comment: There are the query requirements, anyway, the simplest reason, is if there are multiple max ?

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace view AB as
select wrote.serial_number as SN, count(wrote.serial_number) as NumOfPapers
from wrote
group by wrote.serial_number 
ORDER by NumOfPapers DESC;
```

and

```
select AB.SN, AB.NumOfPapers from AB LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using `NumOfPapers` which is count of `serial_number`

```
   select AB.SN, max(wrote.serial_number)

       from AB, wrote
```

Comment: That didn't work ... it returned the first SN on the list together with the highest SN exists... (i think as expected?), i'm not sure if i was clear enough but i DO look for the max COUNT ...

Comment: please show your table schema and how u expect the results , betetr give an example from your table , for we understand good .

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it figured :

```
create or replace view AB as
select wrote.serial_number as SN, count(wrote.serial_number) as NumOfPapers
from wrote
group by wrote.serial_number;

select AB.SN, AB.NumOfPapers
from AB
where AB.NumOfPapers = (select max(AB.NumOfPapers)
                        from AB)
```

Thank you all for your help, you really guided me there !

Comment: Yes, this will return all rows that have the max value; that's slightly different from your original question, which suggested you wanted one row.

Answer (score -1):

I believe your second query asks your database for every AB.SN from AB and the max(AB.NumOfPapers)
Have you tried with a where statement?

```
select AB.SN, max(AB.NumOfPapers)
from AB
where AB.NumOfPapers = max(AB.NumOfPapers)
```

(I haven't tested this though, some adjustments might be needed)

Comment: I tried it before, i get an error for using the group function max() unproperly...